# Referencing a enum object in another class

Tags: java, enums, reference, syntax-error

I'm trying to use a enum object in another class but cant figure out what i have done wrong.

Here is the lines of code in my first class that is trying to reference the second class.

```
Model model = new Model();
Model.Outcome outcome = new getgameOutcome(uChoice,cChoice);
```

And here is the actual object i am trying to reference in the "Model" class.

```
public enum Outcome{
    WIN,LOSS,TIE
}

public Outcome getgameOutcome(String uChoice, String cChoice){
```

and then it continues with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating a new instance, just assigning the return value of a method. Hence, you do not need the `new` operator:

```
Model.Outcome outcome = getgameOutcome(uChoice,cChoice);
```

Comment: when i do that i now get an error saying "The method getgameOutcome(String, String) is undefined for the type RockPaperScissors" RockPaperScissors being the first class that is trying to use the other classes object

Comment: @Volken And that is the problem you should focus on. Notice that `getgameOutcome` expects `(String uChoice, String cChoice)` but you are probably passing instances of `(RockPaperScissors, RockPaperScissors)`.